# Get the loaded slide on fullpage.js slideload callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

I am using fullpage.js and trying to get an element to animate when a slide loads. Each slide is like this:

```
<div class="slide" id="id">
  <div class="slideWording animateHidden">
      <div class="slideWordingTitle">
         <h1 class="fancy"><span>Title</span></h1>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

callback used with fullpage.js

```
afterSlideLoad: function(slideIndex){
            $(".slideWording").addClass("animateVisible animated bounceInDown");
},
```

The only issue is it works on the first slide load but when that happens it adds the class to all the slideWording divs, not just the one on the slide was loaded. So basically the animation only works once. How do I make it add the `animateVisible animated bounceInDown` class to only the `.slideWording` class div in the slide that is loaded so that when a person navigates to a new slide it will run the animation on `.slideWording` every time??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the latest version of fullPage.js ( 2.5.6 at the moment), then do this instead:

```
afterSlideLoad: function(slideIndex){
    $(this).find('.slideWording').addClass("animateVisible animated bounceInDown");
},
```

As can see in [the docs for the callback `afterSlideLoad`](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#afterslideload-anchorlink-index-slideanchor-slideindex), `$(this)` contains the loaded slide.

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', 'thirdPage', 'fourthPage', 'lastPage'],

    afterSlideLoad: function( anchorLink, index, slideAnchor, slideIndex){
        var loadedSlide = $(this);  /// <------ here

        //first slide of the second section
        if(anchorLink == 'secondPage' && slideIndex == 1){
            alert("First slide loaded");
        }

        //second slide of the second section (supposing #secondSlide is the
        //anchor for the second slide
        if(index == 2 && slideIndex == 'secondSlide'){
            alert("Second slide loaded");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This doesnt work unfortunately because it is not targeting the `.slideWording` class. What I want is when the current slide is present have `.addClass("animateVisible animated bounceInDown");` be targeted to the `.slideWording` class. Your solution looks like its trying to target the slide itself.

Comment: I tried this `$(this).find('.slideWording').addClass("animateVisible animated bounceInDown");` but no success either

Comment: @Packy I've updated my answer with `$(this).find('.slideWording').addClass("animateVisible animated bounceInDown");` If it doesn't work it might be for two reason: 1- you are not using the latest version of fullPage.js (2.5.6), or 2: - the lement with the class `.slideWording` is not really inside the slide element.

Comment: Thanks. The issue I had with the `.find` was the plugin was not the most updated. Thanks